# Consecutively number duplicates in a Spark dataframe without a shuffle

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, counting, pyspark

I have a Spark dataframe with time series data (ordered by an index) and a value column.
It looks like this:

```
idx    value    counter
0      2        1
1      2        2
2      2        3
3      1        1
4      1        2
5      0        1
6      0        2
7      0        3
8      0        4
9      1        1
10     1        2
```

The "counter" column is what i'm looking for. When it sees a new value the counter should reset to 1 and start counting until the value changes.

I know it is possible to assign a groupID to every group of consecutive duplicates and then call

```
df.withColumn('counter', row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('groupID').orderBy('idx')))
```

However that would cause a shuffle that isn't necessary since all the elements are already partitioned as needed. I just want a counter that resets when it sees a new value. Is there a way to achieve this with my current partitioning or tell Spark it should work on the groups of consecutive duplicates that I defined but without actually moving the data. The problem is that Window.partitionBy(col) always moves the data.

Comment: It is not possible to do that without shuffling. I think you need two conditions to be fulfilled to solve the task: to have your data ordered by idx and to have all the data on a single executor. The second one is necessary as soon as you compare values sequentially. So, the approach with windows functions is most probably the most efficient one.

Comment: It's possible without a shuffle using `mapPartitions`, but it will require much more code to achieve the same thing...

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Yes, I think I am looking for something like a dataframe-equivalent of mapPartitions. I want to count duplicates based on a certain condition, but I want Spark to keep the partitioning as it is. Do you think it is worth to convert the dataframe to an RDD and apply mapPartitions?

Comment: @Yanikovic DataFrame has `mapPartitions`, at least in scala.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible to do it :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window 

partition = Window.partitionBy("groupID").orderBy("idx")
df = df.withColumn("counter", F.count(F.col("value")).over(partition))

df.show(10, False)
```